# The most pointless shell command you can concoct, based upon a often used shell command

Tags: popularity-contest

Let's waste some time coming up with stupid ideas which are close cousins of good ideas.

- Your useless command doesn't have to fit any minimum or maximum length.
- Do, however, try to turn it into a one-liner if you can.
- No particular requirement for what shells and utilities are used, within reason.
- He who wins, wins.
- More rules will be added if they are added.

Comment: Why was I down-voted, if I may ask?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks a clear spec

Comment: I would guess that you found this site via the hot list or Reddit. There has been a lot of activity recently around questions which do not represent what this site is about, and the long-term members are trying to get things under control. The downvotes will be people who are fed up of subjective nonsense and want to return to objective challenges with clear criteria.

Comment: `cat /dev/random`

Answer (score 3):

Mine is the inverse of "print the kernel arguments you booted with on Linux":

```
cat /proc/cmdline
# turns into...
fgrep -x -f <(awk -F\= 'BEGIN { RS = " "} ; {print $1"="}' </proc/cmdline)\
-v <(curl 'https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt' 
2>/dev/null | awk '/\t+[a-z._]+=/ {print $1}' | tee test2) | tr '\n' ' ' &&
echo
```

[image: a screenshot of the command and output in terminal]

Answer (score 2):

```
ls > /dev/null
```

Simple yet utterly pointless. :-P

For people who don't know shell commands: `ls` lists the files in a directory, and `> /dev/null` basically hides the output.

Comment: short and to the point, I should have anticipated this...

Comment: might be useful to detect errors, also changes access times

Answer (score 2):

Once or twice a week i tend to misspell `ls` so i run `sl`. It's not installed by default in Ubuntu (or perhaps other), so if no magic happens try installing it.

It's quite cool, at least the first few times, as it behaves differently with some common options to `ls` as well and it seems to have blocked signals so you cannot quit it until it's shown you what it can do...

Comment: When I was on Ubuntu, I installed the "sl" package from APT and it was some lame ASCII animation of a [s]team [l]ocomotive... nothing evil like you mentioned. I'm looking for the real thing now on Fedora... it sounds awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if invoking python counts.  This'll start a web server, open your default browser, and show the information you'd usually see on the console **`:-)`**

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer &> index.html & x-www-browser localhost:8000
```

Press F5 a few times, and...

> 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2013 20:27:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2013 20:28:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2013 20:28:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:07] code 404, message File not found 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:07] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [31/Dec/2013 20:28:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

To shut down the server, run the `fg` command, and then press Ctrl-C.